# Reason for Stream class can be used for 'first class loop'

Tags: scala

```
Stream(1,2,3,4).map(_+10).filter(_%2==0).toList
```

I'm curious about the reason why above expression should be executed one element by one element without temporary output(first class loop). For example,

```
cons(11, Stream(2,3,4).map(_+10)).filter(_%2==0).toList
cons(12, Stream(3,4).map(_+10)).filter(_%2==0).toList
12 :: cons(13, Stream(4).map(_+10)).filter(_%2==0).toList
12 :: 14 :: List()
```

Since there is no extra command for changing order of executing. 
I thought executing order would like this,

```
cons(11, Stream(2,3,4).map(_+10)).filter(_%2==0).toList
cons(11, cons(12, Stream(3,4).map(_+10))).filter(_%2==0).toList
cons(11, cons(12, cons(13, Stream(4).map(_+10)))).filter(_%2==0).toList
cons(11, cons(12, cons(13, cons(14, Empty))))).filter(_%2==0).toList
.
.
12 :: 14 :: List()
```

Because map command is lefter than filter command.

... while I'm writing this, I realize that there may be another rule:

'outer command first, inner command later'

and this 'outer -> inner' rule comes faster than 'left -> right' rule.
so, inner map command of below is slower than outer filter command of below.

```
cons(11, Stream(2,3,4).map(_+10)).filter(_%2==0).toList
```

Is my thinking right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because streams are lazy, each element is evaluated on an "as needed" basis.  Consider the following example stream:

```
val es = Stream(2,3,4).map(x=>{println("add");x+10})
                      .filter(x=>{println("filt");x%2==0})
```

The first element is evaluated with the definition of the stream, but nothing else until you ask for it.

```
scala> es(0)
res314: Int = 12

scala> es(1)
add
filt
add
filt
res315: Int = 14
```

Think of it this way, when I asked for `es(1)` it "pulled" 3 through the `map` (adding 10) but it failed to get through the `filter`.  Since we still didn't have the next `es()` element yet, we had to pull 4 through the `map` and this time it passed the `filter` step.

Comment: umm... I already know laziness but I'm confusing because command `Stream(1,2,3,4).map(_+10).filter(_%2==0).toList` ask all values to be evaluation.

Comment: True, `toList` pulls all the elements through the chain, but they're still evaluated one at a time.

Comment: aha... I got it! `.toList` is the key for this question! Thank you so much :)